# Pandas : Row to row calculation

Tags: pandas

Let's say I have a dataframe with 4 columns :

- Country
- Eyes color
- Year
- Number of people

The dataframe is ordered by Country, Eyes color and Year

I would like to calculate the increase or decrease of the number of people from year to year, for each country and Eyes color category.

How can I do that easily with pandas ?

Thanks !

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
Country_grp = df.group_by(['Country'])
Country_grp = Country_grp.get_group('India')
Country_grp[Country_grp.Eyescolor == 'Black', 'Year'].plot()
```

To get all EyesColor in one graph:

Code:

```
Country_grp = df.group_by(['Country'])
Country_grp = Country_grp.get_group('India')
Country_grp['Year'].plot()
```

Explanation:
You can see Increase and Decrease in year in graph.

First Make group of counties :

`Country_grp = df.group_by(['Country'])`

so, i have created new dataframe Counrty_grp which is grouped by Country column in your dataframe.

likewise if you want to get only those rows corresponding to particular country:

`Country_grp = Country_grp.get_group('India')`

You can now apply the filter of eyes color to dataframe:

`Country_grp[Country_grp.Eyes color == 'Black', 'Year']`

The Above filter gets the year whose eyes color is black.